# Override grails.serverURL and application specific grails.propname settings in application.properties file

Tags: configuration, grails, configuration-files

I need to override `grails.serverURL` at runtime *without* having to regenerate the application's WAR file. I have tried various ways of setting `grails.serverURL` in the `application.properties` file and cannot get it to work.

Here is the environment specific portion of `Config.groovy`:

```
environments {
   prod
   {
      grails.serverURL = "http://nonexistentserver.somecompany.com:8080"
      grails.anotherappspecificURL = "xcc://user:password@server.somecompany.com"
   }
```

Basically, our `application.properties` looks like this:

```
grails.env=prod
grails.war.deployed=true
app.grails.version=1.0.4
app.name=myapp
```

Below is one of the ways I have tried to override the settings. These are defined in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.serverURL=http://webserver1.somecompany.com:8080
grails.anotherappspecificURL=xcc://admin:xyzabc123@specificserver.somecompany.com
```

Any help with getting this to work without having to make code changes would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to override values in Config.groovy is to use an external properties file, see:

http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration

Specify an external properties file in Config.groovy, for example:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:app-config.properties"]
```

In the properties file (can be stored in grails-app/conf/) specify the override value:

```
grails.serverURL=http://webserver1.somecompany.com:8080
```

Anytime you need to change the serverURL once the war is deployed just modify the properties file in /WEB-INF/classes/app-config.properties and reload the context.

Comment: Yup, I got that from the documentation.   Problem is, it isn't working.   Our Config.groovy doesn't have anything set for grails.config.location (it's commented out), so I assume that the default external properties file is "application.properties".   It appears that is the case since I can change the setting for "grails.env" and it picks up the proper "environment" configuration that was defined in Config.groovy.

However, I want to override those settings with something else at runtime startup and doing as you noted doesn't have any affect on any of the grails.<propertyname> settings.

Comment: To clarify my original post, the last "code" section is in the application.properties file, not the Config.groovy file, as the comment before that code section might suggest.

Comment: I believe the application.properties contains application meta data that is not merged in with the configuration data contained in Config.groovy.  Therefore, in order to override a parameter that would normally be set in Config.groovy you need to use grails.config.location and not application.properties.

Comment: I understood your last code section was from application.properties and the point of my answer was to say that is not the correct place (i.e., wont work) to override config values.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant, but I noticed you're missing quotation marks in your grails.serverURL

Answer (score 0):

I've found that externalized configuration is a little tricky (as of Grails 1.3.7).  You have to put your file into grails.config.locations in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.config.locations << 'classpath:my-config-file.groovy'
```

But you can't access the properties without adding another file.  I've made it work by putting a new configuration file into `grails-app/conf` and adding it to the classpath by adding the following to `scripts/Events.groovy`.

```
eventCompileEnd = {
    ant.copy(todir:classesDirPath) {
      fileset(file:"${basedir}/grails-app/conf/SecurityConfig.groovy")
    }
}
```

You can find more information at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789506/1269312