# What is the best way to modify a project configuration from within a plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins

As I am trying to write a Grails Plugin, I stumbled upon two problems:

- how do I modify one of the configuration files like `Config.groovy` or `DataSource.groovy` from witin the `_install.groovy`  script? It is easy to append something to those files, but how do I modify it in a clean way? `text.replaceAll()`? Or should I create a new config file?
- how do I get the name of the current application into which the plugin will be installed? I tried to use `app.name` and `appName` but both do not work.

Is there maybe somewhere a good tutorial on creating plugins which I haven't found yet?

Comment: Wow. A question with 1000 views and not a single upvote... Isn't this worth another badge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of editing configuration files from `scripts/_Install.groovy`.
My plugin copies three files to the target directory.

- `.hgignore` is used for version control,
- `DataSource.groovy` replaces the default version, and
- `SecurityConfig.groovy` contains extra settings.

I prefer to edit the application's files as little as possible, especially because I expect to change the security setup a few years down the road.  I also need to use properties from a `jcc-server-config.properties` file which is customized for each application server in our system.

Copying the files is easy.

```
println ('* copying .hgignore ')
ant.copy(file: "${pluginBasedir}/src/samples/.hgignore",
         todir: "${basedir}")
println ('* copying SecurityConfig.groovy')
ant.copy(file: "${pluginBasedir}/src/samples/SecurityConfig.groovy",
         todir: "${basedir}/grails-app/conf")
println ('* copying DataSource.groovy')
ant.copy(file: "${pluginBasedir}/src/samples/DataSource.groovy",
         todir: "${basedir}/grails-app/conf")
```

The hard part is getting Grails to pick up the new configuration file.  To do this, I have to edit the application's `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`.  I will add two configuration files to be found on the classpath.

```
println ('* Adding configuration files to grails.config.locations');
// Add configuration files to grails.config.locations.
def newConfigFiles = ["classpath:jcc-server-config.properties", 
                      "classpath:SecurityConfig.groovy"]
// Get the application's Config.groovy file
def cfg = new File("${basedir}/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy");
def cfgText = cfg.text
def appendedText = new StringWriter()
appendedText.println ""
appendedText.println ("// Added by edu-sunyjcc-addons plugin");
// Slurp the configuration so we can look at grails.config.locations.
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(cfg.toURL());
// If it isn't defined, create it as a list.
if (config.grails.config.locations.getClass() == groovy.util.ConfigObject) {
    appendedText.println('grails.config.locations = []');
} else {
    // Don't add configuration files that are already on the list.
    newConfigFiles = newConfigFiles.grep {
      !config.grails.config.locations.contains(it)
    };
}
// Add each surviving location to the list.
newConfigFiles.each {
    // The name will have quotes around it...
    appendedText.println "grails.config.locations << \"$it\"";
}
// Write the new configuration code to the end of Config.groovy.
cfg.append(appendedText.toString());
```

The only problem is adding `SecurityConfig.groovy` to the classpath.  I found that you can do that by creating the following event in the plugin's `/scripts/Events.groovy`.

```
eventCompileEnd = {
    ant.copy(todir:classesDirPath) {
      fileset(file:"${basedir}/grails-app/conf/SecurityConfig.groovy")
    }
}
```

Ed.

Comment: that's great code for adding new config files. I still wonder what's the best way to change (for instance) the default dataSource configuration... Maybe I just add a comment to the top of the old file and overwrite the config in my new external files...

Comment: Thanks.  I figure that the default `DataSource.groovy` is not very valuable and easy to replace, so I just overwrite it with my own.

Answer (score 3):

You might try changing the configuration within the MyNiftyPlugin.groovy file (assuming that your plugin is named my-nifty).  I've found that I can change the configuration values within the doWithApplicationContext closure.  Here's an example.

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->  
  def config = application.config;
  config.edu.mycollege.server.name = 'http://localhost:8080'
  config.edu.mycollege.server.instance = 'pprd'
}
```

The values you enter here do show up in the grailsApplication.config variable at run time.  If it works for you, it will be a neater solution, because it doesn't require changes to the client project.

I must qualify that with the fact that I wasn't able to get Spring Security to work by this technique.  I believe that my plugin (which depends on Spring Security) was loaded after the security was initialized.  I decided to add an extra file to the grails-app/conf directory.

HTH.

Comment: hm. that sounds good - this way I could slurp another config into the main config...

Answer (score 1):

For modifying configuration files, you should use [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper):

```
def configParser = new ConfigSlurper(grailsSettings.grailsEnv)
configParser.binding = [userHome: userHome]
def config = configParser.parse(new URL("file:./grails-app/conf/Config.groovy"))
```

If you need to get application name from script, try:

```
metadata.'app.name'
```

Comment: problem with the slurper is that if I wannt to add a configuration property at install-time, I would have to slurp the config, modify it and serialize it to disk again. But the serialisation will remove all comments :-(