# Spring security login process not working

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

I am using spring security plugin for logging in user. I am using both AJAX as well as Normal login methods..The code seemed to work fine till it was running on the embedded server but when I pushed the war to the apache Tomcat 7 , then when ever I am logging in, the login process stops and shows

http://localhost:8282/j_spring_security_check

in the address bar when using normal login and shows

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8282/home/j_spring_security_check"

when using ajax login. However the process is stopped but the user is logged in...I am not able to figure out what went wrong..

Comment: Is there a corresponding error in your tomcat server log?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a little more information for anyone to answer accurately.  A 500 error is pretty generic 'catch-all' error that means something went wrong on the server and that's about it.

The first thing you'll need to check is your tomcat server log.  There should be a corresponding error in the log file that will explain in detail what happened.  If your unsure where the log file is do some research on the web and become a little bit more familiar with tomcat.  Spending the time to learn the basics will pay off later.  Update your answer once you have the error from the log file and I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `grails.plugins.springsecurity` configuration settings.  I think that `localhost:8282` should be replaced by the domain name and port of the server that is hosting your authentication server.  Spring Security logs you in by sending the client's browser an HTTP redirect to the authentication service, so `localhost` would redirect him to his own computer, which is probably not what you want.

I keep a little properties file in each application server with the authentication server, so my apps will get that info from the environment.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789506/1269312 for more information on how to do that in a plugin.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when i was using `<g:form .. />` for the login form, instead of the normal `<form .. />` .

You have to set also the default redirect link, in Config.groovy to something like this.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/'
```